# is 3/8 inch nap roller ok for painting a door?

Tags: doors, paint

I'm painting a brand new pre-primed interior door a semi gloss white.  Would a 3/8 nap roller be okay if I want a smooth finish?

Comment: It will give you a slightly stippled finish (any roller will). If you need absolutely smooth you would have to spray it.

Comment: Or if you want a brushed finish with roller speed, use "roll and tip" technique.  It's quite easy and the tipping doesn't cost you much speed.

Answer (score 1):

As Jimmy stated, it will give a dimpled texture to the door, not so desirable. If you want roll on ease, use a foam roller.